# Setting up integration tests for spring boot microservices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have two Spring Boot Applications, which eventually call an external REST API. The structure is somewhat like follows:

`App A -> App B -> External REST API`

I would like to write integration tests, such that I mock the external REST API's responses, but can test requests being sent to App A. What would be the best way to do so in Spring?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `wiremock`. Its very easy to set it up and mock external calls. Check out wiremock.org.